# VUE, VUEX, STATE меняется сам

Tags: vue.js, vuex

такая проблема:

Есть компонент с редактируемыми списками: сначала выбираю список, потом редактирую.
Для того что проверять внесены ли изменения в список, в store есть два state:

```
 state: () => ({
    listActive: {},
    listOriginal: {}
});
```

В компоненте с выбором списков есть функция, которая при выборе списка для редактирования, загружает в оба эти state один и тот же список(получаю по api):

component.vue

```
 this.$store.dispatch('loadList', _list);
```

store.js

```
actions: {
    loadList({state, commit, getters}, _list){
       commit('setList', _list);
       commit('setListOriginal', _list);
    },
}
...
mutations: {
    setList(state, _list) {
       state.listActive = _list;
    },
    setListOriginal(state, _list) {
       state.listOriginal = _list;
    },
}
```

В результате все присваивается нормально, НО, при дальнейшей изменении state.listActive, почему-то так же меняется и listOriginal, хотя мутация listOriginal больше не вызывается?
Подскажите, что я упустил? Спасибо